# Добавление в динамический массив объектов

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь добавить объект в массив, вроде бы использовал, похожий, но в том случае не надо было добавлять уже существующий объект в массив. Программа завершает свою работу, на третьем добавлении, а то и вовсе на втором. 
И ещё вопрос: Я с могу менять объект, так как я его передаю? Это же почти тоже, что и через указатель?

Прошу вас указать проблему.

Вот, собственно, код:

```
void addPacient(Patient &p){
        if(p.getAge() < 18){
            throw AgeException();
        } else{
            addDays();
            ++count_places;
            if(places != nullptr){
                Patient *temp = places;
                places = new Patient[count_places];
                for(int i = 0; i < count_places - 1; i++){
                    places[i] = temp[i];
                }
                delete []temp;
                places[count_places - 1] = p;
                //cout << places[count_places - 1].getName() << endl;
            } else{
                places = &p;
                //cout << places->getName() << endl;
            }

        }
    }
```

И ещё вопрос: Таким образом, как я передаю объект в метод, я смогу изменять его? Это то же, что и передача через указатель?

Comment: ну на самом деле ссылка и указатель это разные вещи. По контексту - `places` - `Patient *` как вы делаете `places = &p` это некрасиво, вы потом сделаете `delete[] places` т.е. по сути вызов удаления массива для 1 элемента. UB, память может вполне пострадать.

Comment: Что такое у вас `places`, где и как объявлено, инициализировано и т.д.? И - у вас то передается `Patient` как `&p`, то как `new` - у вас **обязательно** выскочит либо утечка памяти, либо попытка удаления того, что удалять нельзя... так что то, что она ложится - это далеко не худший результат :), куда хуже, если она бы работала...

Comment: `places` - указатель типа `Patient`, по-умолчанию инициализирован `nullptr`